# REST CLoudant IBM MobileFirst 8 JavaScript Adapter Cannot Add Users POST

Tags: javascript, rest, ibm-mobilefirst, cloudant, mobilefirst-adapters

Unable to add/update a document in my cloudant nosql db , create a document users and add the values : username,fullname,emailAddress and password

CloudantDBAdapter-impl.js

```js
CloudantDBAdapter-impl.js

var DATABASE_NAME = 'test';

function addEntry(entry) {

 var input = {
  method : 'put',
  returnedContentType : 'json',
  path : DATABASE_NAME + '/' + 'users', 
  body : {
   contentType : 'application/json',
   content : entry
  }
 };

 var response = MFP.Server.invokeHttp(input);
 if (!response.id) {
  response.isSuccessful = false;
 }
 return response;

}
```

The connection to the database is successfull as the getFeed returns document id and rev id

Swagger Docs:

[Image Response from input parameter in swagger docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvgbU.png)

inserted params :

["username":" user1","fullName":"FullName","emailAddress":"test@host.com","password":"12345"]

[ibm mfp server cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnGEr.png)

Comment: What is the result you see ? Do you get an error in the messages.log

Comment: Here is my log file https://pastebin.com/5JUDakGy

Comment: The error you see is from Analytics nodes and that is unrelated to the issue. Do you see anything more? Even better, upload the complete log from when the issue was recreated